# Spring WS Jboss Empty request, empty response & isSameNode fault issue

Tags: soap, jboss, spring-ws

Getting below error when hitting my camel-spring-ws in jboss

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<env:Header></env:Header>
<env:Body>
    <env:Fault xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
        <faultcode xmlns:valueNS='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>valueNS:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang='en'>isSameNode</faultstring>
    </env:Fault>
</env:Body>
```

The same war is working fine in different jboss server.

JBoss server used : 5.0

According to documentation :

> Returns whether this node is the same node as the given one. 
>   This method provides a way to determine whether two Node references returned by the implementation reference the same object. When two Node references are references to the same object, even if through a proxy, the references may be used completely interchangeably, such that all attributes have the same values and calling the same DOM method on either reference always has exactly the same effect.

Can anyone tell me what the issue is relative to jboss and spring ws. I coudn't see anything in logs.

Sample Req :

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:off="http://services.dnb.com/OfficerProductServiceV1.0">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <off:OfficerSearchRequest>
     <OfficerSearchRequestDetail>
        <InquiryDetail>
           <OfficerName>
              <LastName>HAR</LastName>
           </OfficerName>
           <OfficerAddress>
               <PrimaryTownName>Test</PrimaryTownName>
            </OfficerAddress>
           <IncludeResignedIndicator>true</IncludeResignedIndicator>
           <OfficerType>DIS</OfficerType>
        </InquiryDetail>
        <InquiryReferenceDetail>
           <!--0 to 5 repetitions:-->
           <CustomerReferenceText>fwe2311</CustomerReferenceText>
           <CustomerReferenceText>ad4234es</CustomerReferenceText>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <CustomerBillingEndorsementText>test</CustomerBillingEndorsementText>
        </InquiryReferenceDetail>
     </OfficerSearchRequestDetail>
  </off:OfficerSearchRequest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with Jboss faulty soap jars which result in empty request being sent to spring-ws.

To rectify the issue.

Add the following bean configuration to force the use of sun's saaj implementation in spring-ws-servlet.xml file

```
<!-- force use of Sun SAAJ implementation -->
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="messageFactory">
        <bean
            class="com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.SOAPMessageFactory1_1Impl"></bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Jboss doesn't pick up the saaj from jdk 1.6. So you have to add the folowing dependencies to your pom.xml file

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
  </dependency>
```